# Xamarin Forms, Android, Segmented Control is getting messed up after tabbing to another Tab Bar Page then return it its Tab Page again

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, segmentedcontrol

I searched for the same issue that I'm facing but could not find it.

My App has 5 pages:
1- Shell Page that has Tab Bar with 5 Tabs and I navigate between tabs using `<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageName}/>` .
2- First Tab.
3- Second Tab which has Segmented Control with 3 children (option1, option2, option3).
4- Third Tab.
5- Forth Tab.
6- Fifth Tab.

When I tab on (second tab) and choose (option2) or (option3) it work and looks fine, but the issue when I tab an (first tab) or (third tab) then tab back on (second tab) and choose (option1) or (option2) or (option3), the segmented control looks mess and loose its format and put text on start instead of center as in below screenshot.

This happens only on when I run the solution on any Android emulator with any Android version, iOS works fine with the same Xaml.

this is Xaml for the Shell Page:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   x:Class="myApp.AppShell">
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle"
           TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor"
                Value="#f4f3f3" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor"
                Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor"
                Value="#808080" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor"
                Value="#f4f3f3" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor"
                Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor"
                Value="#808080" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ShellItem"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

    <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
</Shell.Resources>

<TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar" >
    <Tab Title="first" 
         >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:firstPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="second"
         >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:secondPage}" Title="second" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="third"
         >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:thirdPage}" Title="third" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="forth"
         >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:forthPage}" Title="forth" />

    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="fifth"
          >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:fifthPage}" Title="fifth" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

here is Xaml for the second page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Plugin.Segmented.Control;assembly=Plugin.Segmented"
         x:Class="myApp.secondPage"
         >
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="15" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <controls:SegmentedControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="NewAdSegmentedControl" 
                    TintColor="Black" SelectedTextColor="White" SelectedSegment="0" >
                    <controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
                        <controls:SegmentedControlOption x:Name="firstOption"  Text="1st option" />
                        <controls:SegmentedControlOption x:Name="secondOption" Text="2nd option" />
                        <controls:SegmentedControlOption x:Name="thirdOption" Text="3rd option" />
                    </controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
                </controls:SegmentedControl>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

here is Xaml for third page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="myApp.thirdPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text=""/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

here is a gif representing the problem.

[image]

Please assist...

Comment: We do not have `control:SegmentedControlOption`, could provide it?

Comment: Thanks Wendy for your reply, I’m using Plugin.SegmentedControl.Netstandard.

Comment: According to you xaml, i test on my own, could not reproduce. I need more information with code.

Comment: I added a gif photo for my problem, please see it and tell me which code you need and I will provide.

Comment: Provide the code of second and third tab page. Or a simple example which could reproduce the error for me.

Comment: I provided the code of all pages up there

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, i guess it may cause by the border size of text. I change the position in the grid, awesome it works.

```
 <controls:SegmentedControl
                    x:Name="NewAdSegmentedControl"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    SelectedSegment="0"
                    SelectedTextColor="White"
                    TintColor="Black">
                    <controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
                        <controls:SegmentedControlOption x:Name="firstOption" Text="1st option" />
                        <controls:SegmentedControlOption x:Name="secondOption" Text="2nd option" />
                        <controls:SegmentedControlOption x:Name="thirdOption" Text="3rd option" />
                    </controls:SegmentedControl.Children>
                </controls:SegmentedControl>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wendy for your help, I will try it and see the result.